# Delete Specific Backup file through SQL

Tags: sql-server, backup

I've been researching about how to **delete a specific backup file through an SQL query**, but I only find results about "deleting backups older than a date". That is not what I want. I want to keep old backups, but I want to be able to delete a specific backup by its ID.

I can easily remove the entries from the msdb tables and its restore history for a given backup, but I would like to be able to delete the files as well through an SQL query (**I know their full path**, as it is stored in the database), so that they don't keep wasting space in the disk.

The procedure "xp_delete_file" doesn't seem to allow to delete a specific file.

I assume that if there is a procedure to delete old files, there should be some way to delete a specific file. Please don't worry about security here.

Comment: did you have the Backup file name and Path...?

Comment: I do. That's something pretty easy to fetch from the database. I simply would like to be able to call some "DELETE" (or equivalent) on that path.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

May be old but might help someone. **xp_delete_file**  can be used to delete specific backup file. Try the code below:

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_delete_file 0,N'c:\backup\backup1.bak'
```

Comment: After 7 years, I'm changing the accepted answer from my own below, to this one instead. Not sure if this was available in SQL Server 2008 R2, but at this point, I think this is the answer that deserves to be accepted. Thanks very much!

Comment: It's worth noting 1) this does not remove the device info from the database, so it would be better to use [Alexey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21067116/10243001) if the device info is still in the database, and 2) the `0` is specifying that the file to be deleted is a backup file

Answer (score 6):

```
--Define a backup device and physical name. 
USE AdventureWorks2012 ;
GO
EXEC sp_addumpdevice 'disk', 'mybackupdisk', 'c:\backup\backup1.bak' ;
GO
--Delete the backup device and the physical name.
USE AdventureWorks2012 ;
GO
EXEC sp_dropdevice ' mybackupdisk ', 'delfile' ;
GO
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188711.aspx

Comment: i am using this method but i am not able to delete the file from server .

Comment: Do you get an error? Maybe you need to have enough permissions. Requires membership in the diskadmin fixed server role. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188903.aspx

Comment: Something about this method that confused me is that the physical name needs to be an absolute path.  Using the relative path `'backup1.bak'`, I was able to successfully create a backup and see the backup file in the default backup folder, but when I tried dropping the device, the device info was only removed from the database and the file remained in the backup folder.  I'm not seeing this mentioned in the documentation.  It's just my personal experience.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I needed.

```
xp_cmdshell 'del c:\backup\file.bak'
```

It may be needed to activate the command, through:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO

RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Comment: As a heads-up: xp_delete_file will connect to the file you specify, VERIFY that it's a SQL Server backup file, and then ONLY delete it IF it's older than the time-stamp specified. The dos DEL command is fine as 'dumb' option - whereas xp_delete_file provides a bit of 'extra' protection/logic.

Answer (score 1):

Create a backup-device, with a physical name that points to the backup-file:

```
exec master..sp_addumpdevice @devtype = 'disk',
@logicalname = '<logical_name>',
@physicalname = '<path + physical filename>'
```

Then, execute:

```
exec master..sp_dropdevice '<logical_name>', delfile
```

And your file has gone!

Physical filenames can be found in the table 'msdb..backupmediafamily'